SSl Channels indicator technical library 1.4.3 how to implement it in Python
I have not been able to implement the SSLChannels indicator from the Technical 1.4.3 library in my trading robot, the function asks for 3 parameters but it does not work for me. In the TA Library any indicator responds well to me, but not in the Technical 1.4.3 Library. I use the same DF from the TA library, the DF formats influence.
How to implement SSL Channel indicator from the Technical 1.4.3 library

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
